ServiceBus, Managed ID, Azure Functions and App Configuration not working together
So I have a solution which is using App Configuration and Managed Identity.
A function app is linked to ServiceBus as a trigger, to use managed identity it needs a configuration parameter called ServiceBusConnection__fullyQualifiedNamespace. If I add that to me local.settings then the functions will run. So I know the ServiceBus and Identity is set up correctly.
If I add this to my App Configuration then it won't run, in App Configuration you have to replace the __ with a : or similar.
When the function app starts I can look at the configuration settings. And in those settings I can see the ServiceBusConnection:fullyQualifiedNamespace correctly and the provider is App Configuration, so I know that the connection to App Configuration is working okay.
I have tried many combinations and so far have not made any progress. The errors I get vary depending on setting but usually
"The listener for function 'Functions.TbQueueTrigger' was unable to start. Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus: The connection string could not be parsed; either it was malformed or contains no well-known tokens"
But the string contains exactly the same (FQN) as the local.settings. Now this is when I have the settings in both local.settings AND AppConfiguration. If I look in the Config data I can see the App Configuration choices and not the local.settings.
If I remove the parameters from local.settings then the error is
"The listener for function 'Functions.TbQueueTrigger' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus: Service Bus account connection string with name 'ServiceBusConnection' does not exist in the settings. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting."
So I looks like the function trigger is NOT looking in App Configuration at all. In which case the Run is decorated as such
   public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("notifications-dev", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
        ServiceBusReceivedMessage message
        )

So what am I missing? How can I force the trigger to use App Configuration here? Is there a better way to decorate the function or ensure that the ServiceBus is set up correctly?
thanks!

Please share your Program.cs file.

@paulinventome Make sure your Azure Function App is set up to read from Azure App Configuration by implementing the AddAzureAppConfiguration() method in Program.cs and enabling Managed Identity for authentication.

Why are you not using Azure Key Vault for your settings?


ServiceBus, Managed ID, Azure Functions and App Configuration not working together

It worked for me using below process:
Firstly created a function and deployed to azure and then in Environment Variables:

I have given Azure  Service Bus Receiver role to Function app's identity:

Output:

If you have integrated in App Configuration service then you need to follow steps:
Firstly create:

then IAM give the  App Conjuration Data Owner and Contributor role:

Then wait for 10 min and then add this to Environment Variables:

@Microsoft.AppConfiguration(Endpoint=https://rithwik98.azconfig.io; Key=test)
After adding then pull reference.
Output:


That's interesting but now I have to have a local Environment variable pointing to App Configuration just for this. I have a whole suite of solutions and the only environment variables I have across dev/staging/prod is the Environment they are and the end point of App Configuration. Everything is pulled from there.
It looks like this isn't possible with ServiceBus then? Despite the docs suggesting that it should be able to pull the setting from App Configuration?
Is it possible to just get the ServiceBus decoration to pick this up from an App Configuration string?

Also we are using Labels in App Configuration based on the environment that code is running in and by hard coding that key there is no way for it to pull the label from the current environment?

If you are using App configuration, for first time you need to pull the reference then only this works. AFAIK, this is the only way without changing any part of code.

@RithwikBojja Not sure I understand your last comment. It looks like the above decoration on the Run method is hardcoded to look only at local settings. That's the core issue - The
@Microsoft.AppConfiguration(Endpoint=https://rithwik98.azconfig.io; Key=test)
Is a workaround that in the case of my set up isn't going to work. I am pulling the AppConfiguration end point (correctly) from my App Settings for each deployment of the code and also using a label.
I don't believe there is any way in that line to pull then endpoint from a setting? Or the key? Or a label?

NO, if your data is in app configuration, this is the only way.
